# XML read through excel VBA

Tags: excel, xml

I'm trying to read multiple data inside an XML file and I already have 2 working scripts but for this it doesn`t work. My other XML files are build differenty

When I try following code which I found on the forum and seems most comparable, it doesn't see any nodes. the main node results in 0 so the `for each` loop skips to the ending immediately.

When I look at the parse error the reason is: "**Error opening input file: 'sequence_schema.xml'. The system cannot locate the resource specified**":

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub testing()
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, mainNode As Object, Node As Object, child As Object, child2 As Object
    Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.xml"
    Set mainNode = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//SEQUENCE")

    For Each Node In mainNode
        For Each child In Node.ChildNodes
            Debug.Print child.BaseName & " :" & child.Text
            For Each child2 In child.ChildNodes
               Debug.Print child2.BaseName & " : " & child2.Text
            Next
        Next
    Next Node
End Sub
```

Here is how the xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEQUENCE Format="2.0" Name="hardware\bbx" xmlns="x-schema:sequence_schema.xml">
  <PASSPORT Frozen="No" Type="Production" AccessModifyGroups="All" AccessDisplayGroups="All" 
   Version="1.0" ReviseTime="28/11/2018 11:36:13.384" Revisor="Wesley" CreateTime="11/01/2012 
   17:38:14.765" Creator="Wes" Description="">
    <CUSTOM>
      <CUSTOM_PARAM Name="SendLotEndSignal" Value="0"/>
    </CUSTOM>
  </PASSPORT>
  <STEPS>
    <STEP SeqEndCleanRecipe="NO_RECIPE" Recipe="STANDARD\205C" Chambers="B2B35" SectionName="Steps">
      <CUSTOM>
        <CUSTOM_PARAM Name="Type" Value="PAAP"/>
        <CUSTOM_PARAM Name="Block" Value="B2"/>
      </CUSTOM>
    </STEP>
    <STEP SeqEndCleanRecipe="NO_RECIPE" Recipe="STANDARD\110C" Chambers="B2B14" SectionName="Steps">
      <CUSTOM>
        <CUSTOM_PARAM Name="Type" Value="PAHP"/>
        <CUSTOM_PARAM Name="Block" Value="B2"/>
      </CUSTOM>
    </STEP>
  </STEPS>
</SEQUENCE>
```

In the end I want to extract next values:

- Recipe = STANDARD\205C
- Chambers = B2B35
- Value = PAAP
- Value = B2
- Recipe = STANDARD\110C
- Chambers = B2B14
- Value = PAHP
- Value = B2

Comment: The error message tells you it can't find the XML file used in the namespace. It can't parse it if it can't find it to read it. You're going to need to put that schema file in the proper location (like in the same folder as your XML file) or specify a path to it in the namespace declaration.

Comment: when I call the file using `dir` combined with `*.xml` then it retrieves the correct file so I don't think it is because of the file location or path? Is there another way to check?

Comment: *"Error opening input file: 'sequence_schema.xml'. The system cannot locate the resource specified":* says specifically that the resource 'sequence_schema.xml' cannot be located. That's *file not found*, which means the file isn't in the proper location. There's nothing else to check - the error message is pretty specific and clear.

Comment: when I change the line `xmlns="x-schema:sequence_schema.xml"` in the XML file to `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` (which I was using in my other XML files) it works. How can I have it working with the new format?

Comment: Because it's not looking for the file 'sequence_schema.xml' anymore, because you removed that from the XML. That should be pretty clear, too.

Comment: ok thank you for the input! I did not know that there was another file that I had to look for but indeed, I found it in another folder and when copying the schema file to the same folder, it works. It is located in the parent folder. Is there a way to refer to this in all the XML files that I load from subfolders without copying the schema file to each subfolder?

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comment, you can specify a relative path to the file in the namespace declaration. Also, to help you with your actual question, you should be doing the XPATH expression `//STEPS`, and you're wanting to read *attributes* of the nodes, not the node text. A search here for *[vba] read XML attributes* may find something that helps you get started.